# VLOOKUP formula #Name errors

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formulas

I am using Excel 2011 for Mac.

I am only getting #NAME? errors when I try to lookup for duplicates in another worksheet in the same workbook.

The current formula: 
`=VLOOKUP(A1,NASM,3,FALSE)`

when I tried wrapping NASM (the worksheet I am trying to lookup) in single marks ('') an excel Formula Error dialog prevents me from calculating the formula

2005 Excel apparently let users check a box in the calculation section that 'Accept labels in formulas check box' but that option is not available in this version.

The values in Column A are all text strings.

How do I resolve this formula issue?

edit: I should mention that this workbook has two worksheets, and the NASM worksheet was imported into this workbook via the "Move or Copy" button

Comment: @rwilson thanks for the reply, however the cells are still returning #NAME? errors, despite updating the formula to: =VLOOKUP(A1,NASM!A, 3,FALSE).   Is it possible the strings in Col A are causing the problem? "A Trace Error" points back to the Col A label

Comment: If the strings in Col A were the problem you would get an #N/A error. Which column has the values that you want to return? You are going to need to append a colon along with that column letter to NASM!A. So if the values to be returned are in Column C, you would write it NASM!A:C. If you need further assistance, come to http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85263/excel-talk and I will troubleshoot your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using VLOOKUP it is important to also reference the columns and not just the sheet name. Using the worksheet name by itself in the "Table Array" portion of VLOOKUP will give you a #NAME? error.

---

### **Sheet With Formula**

### [image]

### Sheet with Lookup Table (NASM)

[image]

Here A2 searches for a match in column A on the NASM sheet. Once the match is found it then returns the value found in column C.

Check-Out Mike Girvin's (The BEST Excel instructor IMO) video on the basics of the VLOOKUP formula in the link below.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GZX2iXfqALs