# Setting the table_array in a VLOOKUP in VBA excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying vlookup in VBA. I am referencing to another sheet within the same workbook but i am getting `#NAME?` as a result.

```
Sub MatchNames()

l_row = Worksheets("Lookup").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lookup_range = Worksheets("Lookup").Range("A2:E" & l_row)

Final_row = Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row

    With Range("BG2:BG" & Final_row)
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=vlookup(RC[-52],lookup_range, 2, False)"

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VLOOKUP formula #Name errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32031377/vlookup-formula-name-errors)

Comment: @Ageonix - I don't think that linked answer is a duplicate. In that linked answer the problem was using the worksheet name as the external range; here it is using a declared var as a named range.

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
l_row = Worksheets("Lookup").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set lookup_range = Worksheets("Lookup").Range("A2:E" & l_row)  '<~~one edit here

With Range("BG2:BG" & Final_row)
    .FormulaR1C1 = "=vlookup(RC[-52]," & lookup_range.address(referencestyle:=xlR1C1, external:=true) & ", 2, False)"  '<~~another edit here
End With
```

The [Range.Address property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837625.aspx) can return the entire path and sheet name. Giving too much is not detrimental.

This might be a better method.

```
    Dim l_row As Long, f_row As Long, sLookup_Range As String

    With Worksheets("Lookup")
        l_row = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        sLookup_Range = .Range("A2:E" & l_row).Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1, external:=True)
    End With

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        f_row = .Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
        With .Range("BG2:BG" & f_row)
            .FormulaR1C1 = "=vlookup(RC[-52]," & sLookup_Range & ", 2, False)"
        End With
    End With
```

Comment: Thank you everyone. @Jeeped I used your solution and it worked perfectly. Out of curiosity, do you know what was the problem in my code?